# How to have a custom connector config file be parsed as java properties format?

Tags: neo4j, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have a custom connector that writes Neo4j commands from a file to Kafka and I would like to debug it. So, I downloaded Confluent v3.3.0 and took time familiarize myself with it; however, I find myself stuck trying to load the connector. When I try to load the connector with its .properties file I get the following error:

```
parse error: Invalid string: control characters from U+0000 through U+001F must be escaped at line 1, column 124
parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 2, column 0
```

I have an inkling that it is trying to parse the file as a JSON file as before this error I got the following error when trying to load the connector:

```
Warning: Install 'jq' to add support for parsing JSON
```

And so I brew installed jq, and now having been getting the former error.

I would like this file to be parsed as java properties format which I thought would be implicit due to the .properties, but do I need to be explicit in a setting somewhere?

**Update:**

I converted the .properties to JSON as suggested by @Konstantine Karantasis, but I get the same error as before but without the first line:

```
parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 2, column 0
```

I triple checked my formatting and did some searching on the error, but have come up short. Please let me know if I made an error in my formatting or if there is a nuance when using JSON files with Kafka Connect that I don't about.

Java properties:

```
name=neo4k-file-source
connector.class=neo4k.filestream.source.Neo4jFileStreamSourceConnector
tasks.max=1
file=Neo4jCommands.txt
topic=neo4j-commands
```

Converted to JSON:

```
[{
  "name": "neo4k-file-source",
  "connector": {
    "class": "neo4k.filestream.source.Neo4jFileStreamSourceConnector"
  },
  "tasks": {
    "max": 1
  },
  "file": "Neo4jCommands.txt",
  "topic": "neo4j-commands"
}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out https://www.confluent.io/blog/simplest-useful-kafka-connect-data-pipeline-world-thereabouts-part-1/ for an example of a valid `json` file being loaded using `confluent` CLI

In your example, try this:

```
{
    "name": "neo4k-file-source",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "neo4k.filestream.source.Neo4jFileStreamSourceConnector",
        "tasks.max": 1,
        "file": "Neo4jCommands.txt",
        "topic": "neo4j-commands"
    }
}
```

Comment: Using your JSON, it loaded. I'll give the article a read as well to see if there is anything else that I can pick up for my project. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Confluent CLI, which you are using to start your connector, tries to be smart about figuring out the type of your properties file. It doesn't depend on the extension name (.properties) but calls `file` on the input file and matches the result against the `ASCII` string.

This complies with the current definition of a java properties file (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.properties) but it should be extended to match files encoded in UTF-8 or files that contain escaped unicode characters.

You have two options.

1. Transform your properties to JSON format instead.
2. Edit the CLI to match the file type returned when running `file <yourconf.properties>`

Comment: Hey @Konstantine Karantasis, I tried the first option as I don't quite know how to approach the second. My understanding of CLIs is pretty basic. Though, after converting to JSON I've been getting a new error saying that I have an invalid numeric literal. I've triple checked my formatting and searched the error, but have come up short.

Comment: Are you able to parse your json with `jq` alone?

Comment: To my best understanding, yes. Just using "cat <my-file.json> | jq ." it spits out my JSON with slightly different formatting.